# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, appium, ui-automation

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The Android SDK root folder '/usr/local/share/android-sdk' does not exist on the local file system. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.168.100.111', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_333'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The Android SDK root folder '/usr/local/share/android-sdk' does not exist on the local file system. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details
at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:381:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.168.100.111', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_333'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
[INFO ] 2023-06-06 17:36:48.052 [main] BaseTest - Test case TC_InstallApp started successfully
FAILED: installApp

PreRequisite observations before executing the code::

phone is listing when uses adb devices cmd.

I am using Appium 1.18.3 on iOS/Mac trying to execute code on Physical android phone. When executing the script i'm getting the above error.